# Module build failed - sass-loader

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, webpack, vuetify.js

I just updated Vuetify this evening but it appears to have broken my web app. I've followed all the instructions but the issue seems to be with sass-loader.

This is the error I'm getting.

`Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):`

I've seen quite a lot of people post about this but there doesn't seem to be a proper fix for it. I've tried all the typical ones; rebuilding node_modules, deleting cache, etc but still this problem persists.

Does anyone know what the issue is?

NPM Version: 6.9.0 -
NodeJS Version: 10.16.2

Packages installed:

```
@mdi/font@3.9.96
@vue/cli-plugin-babel@3.10.0
@vue/cli-plugin-eslint@3.10.0
@vue/cli-service@3.10.0
axios@0.18.1
chart.js@2.8.0
deepmerge@4.0.0
fibers@4.0.1
fsevents@2.0.7
material-design-icons-iconfont@3.0.3
sass@1.22.9
sass-loader@7.1.0
vue@2.6.10
vue-router@3.1.1
vue-sweetalert2@1.6.4
vue-template-compiler@2.6.10
vuetify@2.0.5
vuex@3.1.1
```

vuetify.js

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
    icons: {
        iconfont: 'mdi',
    },
})
```

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
      disableHostCheck: true
    },
    configureWebpack: {
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.s(c|a)ss$/,
            use: [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                options: {
                  implementation: require('sass'),
                  fiber: require('fibers')
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueSweetalert2 from 'vue-sweetalert2'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify'
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css'
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'

Vue.use(VueSweetalert2);

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 1):

I vaguely recall dealing with something like this a couple weeks ago.

Here are some things you can try

> remove `dart-sass` and `npm-sass` packages. only `sass` package is needed
>      update `sass-loader` to ^7.1.0

from: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/7950#issuecomment-519192389

Another option seems to be using `node-sass` as a dev dependency.

It may be related to the way you're including vuetify (a-la carte?) Can you provide more info?

Comment: Check my original post mate. I have included everything now.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when earlier `npm install` to install dependencies are made with one version of Node and then later Node version is downgraded because of some other reason.
Run `npm rebuild` to fix this.